# Evaluate the limit of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{2}{n}\left[ \left( \frac{3i}{n} \right)^3+\frac{5i}{n}+2\right]$ when $n\to\infty$

Tags: limits, summation

> How would I evaluate:
>   $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{2}{n}\left[ \left( \frac{3i}{n} \right)^3+\frac{5i}{n}+2\right]$$

So far, I have cubed the inner bracket and taken the $\dfrac{27}{n^3}$ outside to get: 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{54}{n^4}\left(i^3+\frac{5n^2i}{27}+\frac{2n^3}{27}\right).$$

Then I would take the summation of each individual term while substituting the summation of $i^3$ from $i=1$ to $n$ as $(n^2(n+1)^2)/4$.

What is confusing me here is the other terms, because they still $n$ and $i$ mixed together, I don't know to to deal with them.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course, this can be massively simplified with a bit of integration...

Consider the function $f:x\mapsto2((3x)^3+5x+2)$, then the $n$th sum is $$
\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nf\left(\frac{i}n\right),
$$that is, the $n$th Riemann sum of $f$ on the interval $(0,1)$. Since $f$ is continuous, the limit exists and is
$$
\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm dx = \left.2\left(3^3\frac14x^4+5\frac12x^2+2x\right)\right|_0^1=2\left(\frac{27}4+\frac52+2\right)=\frac{45}2.
$$

Answer (score 5):

Managed to solve it after watching some tutorials.

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{2}{n} \left[\left( \frac{3i}{n}\right)^3+ \frac{5i}{n } +2 \right]$$

$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}  \frac{2}{n} \left[27 \sum_{i=1}^n\left( \frac{i^3}{n^3}\right)+ \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{5i}{n } + \sum_{i=1}^n 2 \right]$$

$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}  \frac{2}{n} \left[27 \left( \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4n^3}\right)+  \frac{5(n)(n+1)}{2n } +2n \right]$$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}  \left[54 \left( \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4n^4}\right)+  \frac{10(n)(n+1)}{2n^2 } +4 \right]$$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}  \left[27 \left( \frac{(n+1)^2}{2n^2}\right)+  \frac{5(n+1)}{n } +4 \right]=\frac{27}{2}+ \frac{10}{2}+ \frac{8}{2} =\frac{45}{2}$$

Comment: That should be right, however, it's very much recommended that you use MathJax.

Comment: Did you clarify whether you are supposed to use Riemann sums (leading to a swift and explanatory answer, as suggested in my post) or to plunge into these sums of powers (whose exact values are mostly irrelevant to the problem at hand)?