# Limit as n to infinity of sum to n -- changing upper bound to infinity?

Tags: probability, limits, summation, arithmetic

I am just wondering if, in general,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = \sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i$$

or perhaps it is specific to probability, where I am currently seeing it, such as
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n P(B_i) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty P(B_i)$$
with $B_i$ all being disjoint sets, if that matters.

Is this a definition? If it is, can someone provide me a credible link that confirms it? I believe you, but my google searching is not yielding any links that say it is a definition.

If it is not a definition how could I prove it? It seems to me the standard $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limit wouldn't be very helpful here, as we are not talking about the limit at a point but instead the limit is changing the number of terms summed... thats why I am leaning towards this being a definition.

Thanks

Comment: That's the definiton of $\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i$, so yes, it is true in general.

Comment: Wait, that edit is very confused. Can you give an example of $x_n$ if it doesn't depends on $n$? Are they random variables? Usually random variables are written as capital letters: $X_i$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sorry, if it is confusing. If we are talking probability $B_i$ are disjoint sets and $P$ is some probability measure. What I was trying to say in the edit is that $x_i$ is not some explicit function of $n$. So yes, $x_i$ depends on $n$, but only to the extent that $n$ is telling us which $x_i$ we are using. Basically, I was trying to avoid someone looking at the question and thinking something like $x_i=\frac{1}{n}(n-1)$, in which case I think the property may not be true.

Comment: What is $n$ when you define $x_i=\frac{1}{n}(n-1)$? AGain, you aren't making sense. Do  you mean $x_n=\frac{1}{n}(n-1)$?

Comment: Hmmm. Here I am talking about having a countable number of sets $B_1,B_2, B_3,\dots$. I'm writing this as $B_i$, and then letting $i$ range from $1$ through $infinity$. In my mind this is different from having a function depend on $n$: $x_i$ is not something of the form $f(n)$, $f$ some function.

Comment: Basically, I want to say: don't consider summations such as at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564960/summation-as-the-limit-goes-to-infinity). I want to say this because at this question the answers do not bring the limit inside the sum, so I am unsure of whether my question depends on what I am taking a summation over. _I am going to edit the question to try and make it more clear, and perhaps we can delete all these comments_. Sorry.

Comment: When we write $x_i$, we always mean, unless otherwise stated, that $x_i$ only depends on $i$. That is the notion of "series." There is no other meaning. That problem isn't of the form $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ by its very nature, since there isn't a single sequence $x_1,x_2,\dots$.

Comment: Sorry for my misconception. I will put the $\sum_{i]1}^n x_i$ back in the question, but without the original edit. Also, you helped me clear up a misconception I didn't even know I had, so thank you for that.

Comment: @Thomas $x_i$ *could* be a function if one doesn't follow the convention that $x$ stands for a variable ($y_i$ could certainly be a function). Only context can distinguish one case from another.

Comment: @a.s. But it is never a function of $n$ hen written as $\sum_n x_i$. It is some sequence in some space, whether real numbers or vectors or functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a standard **definition** that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i. \tag 1
$$
You will find this on page 59 of *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, third edition, by Walter Rudin, and in many other books.

In some contexts another definition may be used, in which case the equality of those two things becomes something to be proved.  One such definition is applicable **only if** for every value of the index $i$, the term $x_i$ is non-negative.  It is this:
$$
\sum_{i\,\in\,\{1,2,3,\ldots\}} x_i = \sup\left\{ \sum_{i\,\in\,I} x_i : I \text{ is a finite subset of } \{1,2,3,\ldots\} \right\}. 
$$
One can extend this to a series in which some terms are non-negative and others are negative by writing
$$
\sum_{i\,:\, x_i\ge0} x_i - \sum_{i\,:\,x_i<0} (-x_i).
$$
By this definition the sum would be undefined when the sums of the positive and negative terms both diverge to infinity.  But some series in which the sums of the positive and negative terms are infinite are nonetheless well defined by $(1)$ above.  One such is the alternating harmonic series
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac {(-1)^n} i.
$$
In all series in which the sums of the positive and negative terms both diverge to infinity, the value of the limit $(1)$ depends on the order in which the terms appear.

There are also alternative "summation methods" in which other definitions are used.  Perhaps the most well known of these is "Cesàro summation", named after  Ernesto Cesàro (1859–1906) according to which the sum is
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{ x_1 + (x_1+x_2) + (x_1+x_2+x_3) +\cdots + (x_1+\cdots+x_n) } n.
$$
Every series whose sum is defined by $(1)$ above is Cesàro-summable, and the sum is the same, but some series are Cesàro-summable that are not defined by $(1)$ above; for example:
$$
1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - \cdots
$$
whose Cesàro sum is $\dfrac 1 2$.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful, well-written answer.